# Error in pom.xml with dependencies: Missing artifact org.eclipse.jetty.tests:test-mock-resources:jar:9.1.0.v20131115

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jetty

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.name.MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-jetty-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and I got a problem:

> Missing artifact
>   org.eclipse.jetty.tests:test-mock-resources:jar:9.1.0.v20131115

I see that mvnrepository does not contain this jar file (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.tests/test-mock-resources)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Test resources are not deployed to maven central by the Jetty project.

And example projects are usually not considered dependencies.

Comment: Can  you provide a solution for it?